# How can I prevent the Google Maps Country Redirect?

Tags: google-maps, localization

Google maps has started to redirect me to my local country domain - from `www.google.com/maps` to `www.google.at/maps`.

Is there any way to prevent this without using cookies? Llike the "No Country Redirect" Url for search: `google.com/ncr`?

---

I already tried `www.google.com/maps?hl=en` (which works for most google sites) but maps ignores it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. Since 2017 Google no longer redirect users to country domains for several services, including Google Maps.